# Giving a variable to an object pointer

Tags: php, object, variables

I want to know if a `php` object like `$valuess->$loopFetch['fetch']` can be done in `php`

Answer (score 0):

Let's set up a quick test!

```php
class Test {
  public $data = ["fetch" => "got it!"];
}

$myVar = "data";
$obj = new Test();

print_r($obj->$myVar['fetch']);
```

On my machine running PHP 7.1, it returns:

```
got it!
```

So it works on PHP 7.1! You can also find this documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).